# ClassCastException when interacting with mockito mock

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a simple class

```
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void send(Long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
        //other logic
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

And a unit test

```
@Test
public void sendShouldUpdateIsFinalField() {
    Long id = 44L;
    User user = new User();

    when(userRepository.findById(id)).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
    when(userRepository.save(user)).then(a -> (Answer) invocationOnMock -> {
        assertTrue(user.getIsFinal());
        return null;
    });

    userService.send(id);
    verify(userRepository, times(1)).save(user);
}
```

When I run this test it fails with java.lang.ClassCastException: user.service.UserServiceTest$$Lambda$3/899543194 cannot be cast to user.model.User

on this line in UserService

```
userRepository.save(user);
```

What is the problem here? Thanks is advance.

Comment: Lino is right. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create two lambdas in your second `Mockito.when()`:

```
when(userRepository.save(user)).then(a -> (Answer) invocationOnMock -> {
---------------------------------------^^---------------------------^^
```

You only need one, so remove the `(Answer) invocationOnMock ->` completly:

```
when(userRepository.save(user)).then(a -> {
```